# How to create a twilio video access token using CURL?

Tags: curl, twilio

We are creating a video application using Twilio Video API.

We are not using a standard langage (C#, Node.Js, PHP, Ruby, Phython, Java). So we are using HTTP commands.

In the documentation for creating a room for example (here : https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#), there is a documentation regarding how to create a room using CURL. So we are using these commands :

```
curl -X POST https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms \
--data-urlencode "UniqueName=DailyStandup" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

However for creating an Access Token, there is no example how to do that in CURL. There is only  (C#, Node.Js, PHP, Ruby, Python, Java) here : https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generate-helper-lib

See Screenshot attached.

[image]

Does anyone know how to create an access token using CURL please?

Answer (score 2):

Access tokens can be generated locally in the server, without curl. These are standard JWTs that use the HS256 signing algorithm. The signing key is the secret of the API key that you are using.

The payload of the JWT is going to be a bit tricky to generate. Depending on what grant(s) you want to assign to the token the payload contents are going to vary. My recommendation is that you generate a valid token using one of the Twilio helper libraries, then decode its payload and generate the same format. You can decode a JWT token at https://jwt.io.

Answer (score -1):

To follow up on Miguel's answer, there is documentation on [how to generate Twilio Access Tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens). A Video Access Token requires an `identity` and `video` grant. The `video` grant can optionally contain a `room` property that contains a room name or SID. If a video grant has the room property, the Access Token can only be used to enter the defined room.

The payload of an Access Token with a Video grant looks like this:

```json
{
  "jti": "SKAPIKEY-1648079388",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "philnash",
    "video": {
      "room": "
    }
  },
  "iat": 1648079388,
  "exp": 1648082988,
  "iss": "SKAPIKEY",
  "sub": "ACCOUNT_SID"
}
```

There is also a [Twilio CLI plugin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generate-cli) that can be used on the command line to generate Access Tokens, which you may find useful. When you've installed the plugin, you can use it to generate a token with the command:

```
twilio token:video --identity=<identity>
```

Comment: Thanks but this answer is almost out of topic. The question is not how to generate access token. The question is how to generate access token using CURL. You almost made a copy-paste from the documentation which explains how to generate a token and not how to generate a token using CURL

Comment: You can’t generate an access token using curl, there isn’t an API for it. An Access Token is generated by creating a JWT signed with an API secret as Miguel explained. I did show you a tool that you can use on the command line to generate an access token though, was that not of help?